# Trying to replace stopwords in pandas dataframe, sre_constants.error occurs

Tags: python, pandas

I'm, having a problem with removing stopwords from pandas dataframe. My code goes like this:

```
for word in stopwords: 
  df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(word, '')
```

An I get an error: sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat at position 0.
Is there any solution to the error, or any other way to replace stopwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `df.replace` with `regex=True`:

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
stopwords = ["AAA", "BBB"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Hello", "World", "AAA", "BBB"]})
print( df["name"].replace("|".join(stopwords), "", regex=True))
```

**Output:**

```
0    Hello
1    World
2         
3         
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: That helped. Thanks!